# convert xml file into csv format sing camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

i want to create .xml file into csv file using camel. here is my code

```
 CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
from("file://Input?fileName=test.xml").marshal().csv().to("file://test?fileName=test.csv");
 context.start();
```

But its't creating any file in desired folder "test".

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Separate this line to 4 lines: one method call in each line and see intermediate results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please spend just a bit more time on the Camel docs, and try out the examples, and read the FAQ. And the introduction articles and whatnot.

The code above isn't even valid, as you would need to put it inside a RouteBuilder.

Also when you start CamelContext, read the javadoc of the start method. And read this FAQ
http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Also Camel offers a tracer so you can see the message flow as the messages are being processed. The tracer will be default log this at INFO level to the logger.
http://camel.apache.org/tracer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample using camel

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <from uri="file:src/xmldata?noop=true"/>
      <to   uri="xslt:file:src/main/fruits.xslt"/> 
      <to   uri="file://TESTOUT?fileName=output.csv"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

**sample xml file in src/xmldata folder**

```
<AllFruits xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- All fruits below. -->
<Fruit>
  <FruitId>Bannana</FruitId>
  <FruitColor>Yellow</FruitColor>
  <FruitShape>Moon</FruitShape>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Joe</Name>
     <NumberEaten>5</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>2.6</Weight>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
     <Name>Mark</Name>
     <NumberEaten>8</NumberEaten>
     <Weight>5.0</Weight>
  </Customer>
</Fruit>
</AllFruits>
```

**src/main/fruits.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="Fruit">
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::FruitId" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="NumberEaten" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Weight" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```